# Redhat-ga module.xml and module directory arrangements

Tags: rhel, application, module

I see **Alpha & Beta** mvn dependencies artifact libraries are available for *Redhat Platform*.

But as part of JBoss *EAP* `modules`, I am bit worried how to organize it, if it all I go for some module addition on my own. It's the same even in case of *Wildfly* I hope.

I hope until & unless Redhat offers a support & give a `module.xml`, we could probably not be able to organize the `modules`.

Still I am unaware how we have to organize the module directory. May `module.xml` may explain regards to folder arrangements. Someone may intervene here and help me out regarding this.

As I am yet not tried anything with **GA** releases, I could yet to organize my question with samples over here. You can consider me as a newbie discussing this matter of fact.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you are looking to add a custom module to JBoss EAP. This is covered in the documentation: [Create a Custom Module](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.3/html/configuration_guide/overview_of_class_loading_and_modules#create_a_custom_module) . Does this answer your question?

Comment: Give me sometime I can answer to you back, but at this moment, no. Thanks for your reference. I used to work once with modules directory over EAP platform. As I just had a recall and a cumulative thought made me write this post. Thanks again!